# Spring Data: Fetching values from Entity with @ElementCollection

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My Entity class is:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username" }, name = "uq_username") } })
public class User{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
@NotNull
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "User_Roles", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private List<Role> roles;
```

}

Role class is an enumeration:

```
public enum Role {
ADMIN,
OFFICE_USER,
SUPERVISOR,
MANAGER,
DATA_ENTRY
```

}

Property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` and the tables `user` and `user_roles` (fields: user_id, roles) are created and data inserted successfully. However, querying for data for users with a role is not working. My repository is:

```
@Component
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>, JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

@Query(value = "select usr from User usr where usr.firstName LIKE :username% OR usr.lastName LIKE :username%"
        + " AND usr.roles=:roles")
public List<User> fetchUsersByNameAndRole(String username, Collection<String> roles);

}
```

On passing the following request I am getting error

http://localhost:8080/api/users/search/fetchUsernamesByNameAndRole?username=Thom&roles=SUPERVISOR

```
[org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException: EntityRepresentationModel not found!]
```

If I change Repository method (changing username parameter to String from Collection) to

```
@Query(value = "select usr from User usr where usr.firstName LIKE :username% OR usr.lastName LIKE :username%"
        + " AND usr.roles=:roles")
public List<User> fetchUsersByNameAndRole(String username, String roles);
```

The error becomes:

```
[org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [SUPERVISOR] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [SUPERVISOR] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]]
```

**Question 1:** How can I fetch all users with a name and a particular role (or set of roles) in this scenario?

The code is working if I remove the roles clause, like

```
@Query(value = "select usr from User usr where usr.firstName LIKE :username% OR usr.lastName LIKE :username%")
public List<User> fetchUsersByName(String username);
```

I need the user names only. So I changed code to:

```
@Query(value = "select usr.firstName from User usr where usr.firstName LIKE :username% OR usr.lastName LIKE :username%")
public List<String> fetchUsersByName(String username);
```

But gets the error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String
```

Changing to native query also gives same error:

```
 @Query(value ="select first_name from user  where first_name like ?1%", nativeQuery = true)
```

**Question 2:** Why mapping to List is not working in Spring data? I remember it was working with normal Spring JPA

Comment: Do you want to retrieve `users` with exact set of roles? for example, let's say that userA has two roles:`ADMIN`, `MANAGER`. And then what's the result for request with `roles=ADMIN`?

Comment: @cjlee For a request with roles=ADMIN, I need to fetch the names of all users having ADMIN role

Comment: ou've got a few issues all happening at once here - start with something more simple! Enums are not Strings and so are not interchangeable if the model expects an Enum. If this were a string instead of Enum in your model, you can use something like "select distinct usr from User usr join usr.roles r where r in :roles". This will allow you to pass a collection parameter containing one or more roles and give you the user that matches it. Otherwise, use MEMBER OF for a single role: "select usr from User usr where :role MEMBER OF usr.roles"